# Quick SQL query buttons with ajax update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

Being still a beginner in practice with Php and SQL, I ask you if it is possible to filter the results through keywords.
In practice, I have a table of values where the courses of study and the study topics of the course are stored. By clicking on keywords such as "science", "programming", "mathematics", I would like to perform an SQL query of the results, displaying all the contents containing these words in the 'Course name' column and in the 'Course topic' column.

```
primaryKey | Course name |   Course topic
-----------+-------------+-------------------------------------------
1          |   Math 1    |   Algebra, equations
2          |   Math 2    |   Differential equations, integrals
3          |   Physics   |   Physical Mechanics, thermodynamics
4          |   Chemistry |   Chemical equations, algebra, geometry
```

At the moment I've done a script to retrieve informations from db and perform search in it

What I wish to do is to create "quick-query buttons" to search elements in db, as example

```
+-----------+   +------------+  
|  algebra  |   | equations  |  
+-----------+   +------------+
```

as suggestions to query the db.

Thanks in advance to those who will help me

UPDATE:

script code in the index.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
load_data();
function load_data(query)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"fetch.php",
        method:"post",
        data:{query:query},
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#result').html(data);
        }
    });
}

$('#search_text').keyup(function(){
    var search = $(this).val();
    if(search != '')
    {
        load_data(search);
    }
    else
    {
        load_data();            
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

---

fetch.php file

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("x", "x", "x", "dbName");
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$query = "
SELECT * FROM dbName 
WHERE CName LIKE '%".$search."%'
OR CTopic LIKE '%".$search."%' 
";
}
else
{
$query = "
SELECT * FROM dbName ORDER BY CName";
}
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
$name = $row['CName'];
$topic = $row['CTopic'];

echo "<div class='content'>
            <div>
              <input type='checkbox' id='name' name='q' class='name'>
              <label for='name' class='names'>
                $name
              </label>
              <div class='topics'>
                $topic
              </div>

            </div>
        </div>";
endwhile;
}
}
else
{
echo 'Element not found';
}
?>
```

Comment: Just create a html button with ajax call to the php script you have created. what do you need help with in particular?

Comment: I've created the search box, in which I can write and it works correctly.
How can i do a php call in a form button? Could you help me with the syntax? Thank you

Comment: you can use ajax, or you can submit the html form, if thats what you are asking, check my answer

Comment: I'll check your answer and I'm happy for your help, but the solution still doesn't work. Do you want to help me more?

Answer (score 0):

For ajax request

1.Include Jquery Library in your web page. for eg:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2.Call a function on button click

```
<button type="button" onclick="create()">Click Me</button>
```

3.while click on button ,call create function in javascript.

```
    <script>
    function create () {
          $.ajax({
            url:"test.php", //the page containing php script
            type: "post", //request type,
            dataType: 'json',
           data: {courseName: "algebra", courseTopic: "xyz", email: "abc@gmail.com"}
            success:function(result){

             console.log(result.abc);
           }
         });
     }
<script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
In my php page I've already included Ajax and the search engine is dynamic without page refresh.

In detail, I've the main php page, a php file ("fetch.php") in which I manage the connection with db and in which I get the results to display.
Now, to create "quick button" hints for search, have I to create new php files customized for the new interrogations of the db, or can I use the same "fetch.php" file and pass a custom argument to it?

Comment: you can use the same php script you have and input the predefined searches yourself with some adjustments, instead of using user input just pass your own values to your php script. cant be more specific without the code.

Comment: Okay, I update the question with the script code and the fetch source code

Comment: now on your html create a button <button onclick="load_data("THE VALUE YOU WANT TO SEARCH ")" >

Comment: if you want to search for the topic you need to crate a condition in your php and retrive the topic from sql in a different query

Comment: I tried with your solution (button onclick) but it doesn't work and doesn't update the results shown.

If my query to SQL db is the following:
     $query = "
 SELECT * FROM `dbName` WHERE `CName` LIKE '%algebra%'
   OR `CTopic` LIKE '%algebra%' 
     }

How could i implement the solution in index.php and fetch.php? Thank you again!